# Name space does not exits but I can not reference it too

Tags: database, migration, connection, database-connection

My context is in on the other folder and when I want to add migration I see the name space does not exist. I know I had to add reference
I want To add reference from the current step but each time I check the check box , problem is still there and when I return to this step , I see check box was unchecked

error:

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Infra' does not exist in the namespace 'EvSef' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

[image]